# Processing function does nothing but freezes the program

Tags: java, processing

I'm working on a pathfinding algorithm in processing. If I don't draw a line that crosses the path between the green and the red dot, it works, but if I do, I've got a problem, that if I call a function, the program does absolutely nothing but freezes, and I have no idea why. The pixelss stores what you draw, and there are all kinds of stuff, that don't matter at this problem.
When you paste it to processing, press ctrl+t to auto-format it so you can understand it better, but I'd bet it's a newbie issue.

```
int[][] pixelss = new int[500][500];
void setup() {
  background(255);
  size(500, 500);}
int[][] badcoos = new int[500][500];
void golinego() {
  stroke(200, 200, 255);
  line(30, 30, 470, 470);
  int j = 30;
  int i = 30;
  while (dist(i, j, 470, 470) > 10) {
    stroke(0, 0, 180);
    circle(i, j, 1);
    if (pixelss[i+1][j+1]==0) {
        i++;j++;}
    if (pixelss[i][j]==1) {
      if (pixelss[i][j+1]==1) {
        if (pixelss[i+1][j]==0) {
          i++;}
      } else if (pixelss[i+1][j]==1) {
        if (pixelss[i][j+1]==0) {
          j++;}
      } else {
        i-=1;
        j-=1;}}}}
void draw() {
  stroke(0, 255, 0);
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  circle(30, 30, 10);
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  circle(470, 470, 10);
  if (mousePressed == true) {
    try {
      stroke(0);
      fill(0);
      circle(mouseX, mouseY, 2);
      pixelss[mouseX][mouseY] = 1;
      pixelss[mouseX+1][mouseY] = 1;
      pixelss[mouseX-1][mouseY] = 1;
      pixelss[mouseX][mouseY+1] = 1;
      pixelss[mouseX][mouseY-1] = 1;
      pixelss[mouseX+1][mouseY+1] = 1;
      pixelss[mouseX-1][mouseY+1] = 1;
      pixelss[mouseX+1][mouseY-1] = 1;
      pixelss[mouseX-1][mouseY-1] = 1;
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}}}
void keyPressed() {
  if (key=='r') {
    pixelss = new int[500][500];
    badcoos = new int[500][500];
    background(255);}
  if (key==' ') {
    golinego();}
  if (key=='d') {
    background(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++) {
        if (pixelss[i][j]==1) {
          stroke(255);
          circle(i, j, 1);}}}}}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is getting caught in your `while` loop.
You can see this if you print out the values of `i` and `j` inside the loop. They never meet the condition to escape the loop, so that chunk of code runs repeatedly with no change.

```
while (dist(i, j, 470, 470) > 10) {
  println(i, j);
  // etc...
}
```

This hangs the app because the `while` loop needs to complete before the the `draw` function gets called again to update the screen.

It's not clear to me what you're actually doing in the while loop, but that's where you should look. Either alter your logic inside the loop, or change the condition to ensure that the code doesn't get stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should at least print something when the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is caught.

It looks like you are working with some kind of gui library, make sure you are doing any processing in separate thread from the gui or the gui will become unresponsive and appear to 'freeze' like you describe.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: The try/catch part only affects the drawing, not the pathfinding.